# ZoneAwareError "Unexpected token <" after launching angular 2 app

Tags: angular, typescript

Im getting an error after launching my angular 2 app. What is causing the error and how do I fix it? It looks like its happening when I require @angular/core in main.ts.

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at SystemJSLoader.__exec (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1501265527981:1506:18)
    at entry.execute (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1501265527981:3647:16)
    at linkDynamicModule (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1501265527981:3247:32)
    at linkDynamicModule (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1501265527981:3241:11)
    at getModule (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1501265527981:3215:9)
    at http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1501265527981:3251:16
    at require (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1501265527981:3888:29)
    at Object.eval (http://localhost:5555/app/main.js:2:14)
    at eval (http://localhost:5555/app/main.js:13:4)
    at eval (http://localhost:5555/app/main.js:14:3)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at SystemJSLoader.__exec (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1501265527981:1506:18)
    at entry.execute (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1501265527981:3921:18)
    at linkDynamicModule (http://localhost:5555/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?1501265527981:3247:32)"
```

main.js

```
"use strict";
var core_1 = require('@angular/core');
var platform_browser_dynamic_1 = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic');
var app_config_1 = require('./app.config');
if (app_config_1.APP_CONFIG.ENV === 'prod') {
    core_1.enableProdMode();
}
var app_module_1 = require('./app.module');
platform_browser_dynamic_1.platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(app_module_1.AppModule);
```

package.json

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.10",
...
```

Comment: Yea I've checked the network tab and everything is returning js.

Comment: I would check again.

Comment: I agree with @Jake, anytime I have had this issue it was on the network side, or at the very least what I was receiving from an outside source.